# Microsoft Office log location on windows

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel

Where is Microsoft Office log location on windows? It gives me some problem about file corrupted, but does not specify what exactly is wrong. Where it usually logs. I could not find because I do use Linux... Just where windows puts its log-files?

Comment: There may be something in the system event logs. See [How to view error signatures if an Office program experiences a serious error and quits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/289508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Office does not create log files, but keeps all events in Windows event logs system instead.

If the version of Microsoft Office you are using is 2010 or 2013, you should do the following steps:

1. In **Control Panel**, open **Administrative Tools**.
2. Start **Event Viewer**.
3. In the list of event logs, select **Application**.
4. On the **View** menu, click **Filter**.
5. In the **Event source** list, select **VSTO 4.0**.
6. For installation events, in the **Event ID** box, type **4096**.
7. Click **OK** to see the filtered view.

If you are using Microsoft Office 2007, you can also find MS Office journals in Windows event logs. Not in Application log, but in two separate log categories: **Microsoft Office Diagnostics** and **Microsoft Office Sessions**.